# How to prove that the following matrices in $M_p(\Bbb F_p)$ is similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

How to prove that the following matrices in $M_p(\Bbb F_p)$ is similar:

> Consider two matrices $$(a_{ij})=
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
>     0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \ddots  & \vdots &\vdots\\
>     0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots &  1 & 1\\
>     0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots &  0 & 1\\
>     \end{pmatrix}$$
>    and $$(b_{ij})=
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
>     1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
>     0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \vdots  & \vdots &\vdots\\
>     0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots &  1 & 0\\
>     \end{pmatrix}$$

*I can observe that the characteristic polynomial of $(a_{ij})$=minimal polynomial of $(a_{ij})$=$(x-1)^p$ and the characteristic polynomial of $(b_{ij})=x^p-1=(x-1)^p$*

**Now how do I argue from here that the minimal polynomial of $b_{ij}$ is also $(x-1)^p$?**

Comment: The first $p$ powers of the matrix $\left(b_{ij}\right)$ are linearly independent (because just look at them...), so its minimal polynomial cannot have degree $< p$.

Comment: I'm wondering what an explicit similarity matrix would look like, though.

Comment: Which one is linearly independent? The matrix!!

Comment: I think the two matrices are conjugate by a Pascal matrix (something like, the $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $\left(-1\right)^{j-i}\dbinom{j-1}{i-1}$).

Comment: Hi, I got the answer  without Pascal's triangle. Let's open this question for some day otherwise I will answer my own question. You can post any answer with Pascal's triangle or so. It is actually easy.

Answer (score 2):

$A,B$ are similar because $\dim(\ker(A-I))=1$  ($A$ is a Jordan block) and $\dim(\ker(B-I))=1$ ($B$ is a Frobenius block).