# Show that two matrices are similar in $M_p(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules, jordan-normal-form

**The Problem**: Show that the following two matrices are similar in $M_p(\mathbb{F}_p)$: $$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \ddots  & \vdots &\vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots &  1 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots &  0 & 1\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
and $$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \vdots  & \vdots &\vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots &  1 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$.

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra, $\mathit{3^{rd}}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote.

**My Question**: The same question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3207589/506332). Now, the two matrices have the same minimal polynomial, then since they have the same characteristic polynomial, it follows that they have the same elementary divisor $(x-1)^p$, hence obviously they'd have the same Jordan Canonical Form as well, thus they are similar. This argument is somehow deemed invalid by my professor, and I just couldn't figure out where the invalidity lies-any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be because you argued 'same minimal, same characteristic -> same elementary divisor'. This is incorrect in general. But it is true for this case knowing that the degree of minimal is $p$ with $(x-1)^p$. So, you may have to include this mention about the degree of minimal polynomial.

Comment: @SungjinKim  Thank you for the help! I believe you are suggesting that generally the best we can say is that they are only same up to permutation of the blocks along the diagonal, correct?

Comment: No, consider 4x4 matrix with two 2x2 Jordan blocks of the same eigenvalue 1, and 4x4 matrix with one 2x2 Jordan block of eigenvalue 1 with the rest of diagonals 1. Then the matrices have minimal $(x-1)^2$, characteristic $(x-1)^4$. But, the matrices are not similar.

Comment: Just to rephrase Sungjin’s point, the essential point is NOT JUST that the matrices have the same minimal and characteristic polynomials. Rather, since the minimal polynomial equals the characteristic polynomial, that uniquely determines the Jordan form where every root designates its own block that has all of that eigenvalue.

Comment: @SungjinKim My professor was right-there is still gaps in my understanding and it is now exposed. I am working on it.

Comment: @Eric Thank you! I can see that now-I still need to sort out the counterexample Sungjin gives, but that shouldn't be insurmountable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more rigorous argument, courtesy of @SungjinKim and @Eric: Since the two matrices have the same characteristic polynomial and the same minimal polynomial AND the characteristic polynomial equals the minimal polynomial, it follows that they also have the same invariant factor, namely $(x-1)^p$, hence also the same elementary divisor, namely (also) $(x-1)^p$. Thus there is only one Jordan block in both of their Jordan Canonical Forms, and that Jordan block is the same with 1's along the main diagonal and 1's along the first superdiagonal.

Comment: Trying to reconstruct what the complaint was. You are aware of the fact that Jordan canonical forms are guaranteed to exist only over an algebraically closed field (or some other suitable field), right? Have you verified that both these matrices can be brought into JCF via operations defined over the prime field? Rational canonical forms might serve better here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ahh, I see. This exercise comes from the JCF chapter in D&F so that completely eluded me; but I agree that got to be one of his complaints as well!