# A $4\times 4$ matrix counterexample.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

A question in Dummit & Foote is asking to prove that two $3\times 3$ matrices are similar iff they have the same characteristic and the same minimal polynomial. I was able to prove that. But then the question is asking me to give an explicit counterexample to this assertion for  $4\times 4$ matrices. And I do not know how to give this example.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Consider the case where the matrix has an eigenvalue of multiplicity 4.

Comment: Read the 3rd comment here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687946/show-that-two-matrices-are-similar-in-m-p-mathbbf-p

Comment: From the duplicate: the matrices
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
both have characteristic polynomial $x^4$ and minimal polynomial $x^2$, but since their Jordan canonical forms are different, they are not similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,choose
$A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  1&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  1\\
 0&  0&  0&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) 
$, $B=
\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  0&  0&  1\\
 0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) $. The characteristic and minimal polynomial is $\lambda^4$ and $\lambda^2$.

But $A$ and $B$ are not similar.